# make a docker image created in pre_build available for the build phase on docker hub?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I try to create a docker image based on Oracle Database XE.

The situation is a bit special. Oracle provides a [repository](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images) that contains the scripts needed to create such an image. The images are not directly available on docker hub.

The script creates an image named `oracle/database:18.4.0-xe`

I use that image to copy certain files via the `COPY` statement. See [Dockerfile](https://github.com/diemobiliar/minimized-oraclexe-image/blob/main/18c_xe/Dockerfile#L21).

The idea I had was to use a `pre_build` script to clone the oracle repository, create that image, then simply run the build on docker hub. But it seems that image is created, but not available in the build phase. That `COPY` statement fails as that image cannot be found.

Is there something else to do, to make that image available in the build phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by adding another FROM into the Dockerfile

```
FROM diemobiliar/oraclexe-image:18.4.0-xe as oraclexe

FROM oraclelinux:7-slim

COPY --from=oraclexe --chown=oracle:oinstall\
  ${ORACLE_HOME}/lib/libsqlplus.so\
```

and by also uploading the image into its own repository. Not sure why this works locally but not during the build on docker hub. I assume some Docker version issue. The docker image created in the `pre_build` script is visible also during the build phase, only the `copy --from=...` statement seems to currently have some issues with referencing images directly.

There are more examples on the internet that use that syntax but also rely on BuildKit (which may be more elegant even for my use case but I haven't tried that).

Anyway some sort of workaround was found, so for now I'm good.

Comment: I don't know exactly what's in the diemobiliar oracle image but it should be what you build from this source: https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0

If you look at the diemobiliar source at https://github.com/diemobiliar/minimized-oraclexe-image, they have a minimized version of that image setup for you. However, they seem to have removed things like docker entrypoint initdb from the image itself.

Comment: this question here related to exactly that repository there to be able to publish the image to dockerhub. I'll have a look at the reported issue.

Comment: fyi, i just started looking at that repo yesterday. that dockerfile is a nightmare to look at but my fork has a cleaned up version in the works right now.